# Typescript @Types usage and expectations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, typescript

I am trying to get @types working using npm in an ASP.NET 4 MVC 5 web application in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, ver 3. To be clear this is a medium-sized, traditional ASP.NET MVC LOB project meant to support 5-10K users concurrently. It is not an ASP.NET Core app, single page app, and does not use angular, gulp, webpack, or node.js.

Here are the dependencies in my package.json:

````
```
    "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": ">=3.4.0",
    "@types/chai-as-promised": ">=0.0.29",
    "@types/mocha": ">=2.2.0",
    "@types/mocha-phantomjs": ">=3.4.0",
    "@types/sinon": ">=1.0.0",
    "@types/sinon-chai": ">=2.7.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": ">=2.0.4",
    "jquery": ">=2.0.4",
    "phantomjs": ">=2.1.7"
    }
```
````

The node_modules folder contains all the @types d.ts files in its @types sub-folder. And it includes all the js libraries mentioned specifically by the list of @types. It also includes all the js libraries that all the @types listed depend on, and those that those depend on, recursively.

But, I also have 205 errors stating, for example,

Error TS2688 Cannot find type definition file for 'yauzl'. TypeScript Virtual Projects 1 Active.

So... I'm guessing these are errors thrown by the Typescript build process that is built into Visual Studio Build. And what this seems to be saying is that the build process for the VS Typescript Virtual Process is aware of these dependent, not @typed javascript libraries, but it also believes these js libraries should be providing proper declarations.

It makes me suspicious of the compatibility between ASP.NET 4 MVC 5 and its Typescript Virtual Solution tooling and the ongoing Typescript feature set growth.

But maybe its easy and I just need some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tsconfig.json` file (located at the root of the solution) should have `typeRoots` entry to introduce these files automatically:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...  
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types/"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
      //...
    ]
}
```